# IntelliJ overrides Scala additional compiler options when synced from Gradle

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm working on a Scala project in IntelliJ IDEA, and using Gradle for configuration and dependency management.

Every time I add some new dependency and sync it into IDEA, it rewrites **Additional compiler options** into `-target:jvm-1.8`, what results in a error when I try to make it with IDEA:

```
Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target'
Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.8'
```

So I need to fix it manually.

Can I set target JVM version or compiler parameters (need also `-feature` option) in my **build.gradle**, so it would take them from there?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it rewrites Additional compiler options into -target:jvm-1.8"? How exactly do you sync with IDEA? Is the Gradle build working?

Comment: Using bundled Gradle plugin, **Refresh all Gradle projects** from **Gradle tasks** tool window. Gradle build is working ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `sourceCompatibility = '1.7'` to your gradle build file and then refresh, the project will build normally. Note that this way you cannot have Java 8 source in your code, this is a temporary hack until `Gradleware` or `JetBrains` solve the issue.

You can also tamper with the IDEA project XML that is generated when running `gradle idea`. That would give you the option to include additional flags as well. You can check your current xml by opening the project `.iml` file and identifying what needs to be changed, then use the following code:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
  module {
    iml {      
      withXml {
        def node = it.asNode()
        //modify xml
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Would not recommend it though, as you will have to stick with using `gradle idea` and won't be able to properly import straight from the IDEA, but currently there is no better way to have additional flags. Documentation - [idea plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) and [idea module](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html)

Comment: Is there a solution for this issue? or still only workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution for this for ages, finally found it - sharing for anyone else reading this.

Taken from: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5523902

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
}
```